# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'System.Data.DataRowView' to data type int

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows

I am trying to populate a `DataGridView` based on a comboBox selection. I don't know where I am going wrong - please help..

Here is my code:

```
public void GetTestGroups()
{
    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select LabTestGroupId,GroupName from tbl_LabTestGroup", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        cbTestGroup.DataSource = dt;
        cbTestGroup.DisplayMember = "GroupName";
        cbTestGroup.ValueMember = "LabTestGroupId";           
    }
}

private void cbTestGroup_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("spGetTestNames", con);
        da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LabTestGroupId", cbTestGroup.SelectedValue.ToString());

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);// Error in this line.

        dgvLabTests.DataSource = dt;
    }
}
```

My stored procedure:

```
create procedure spGetTestNames 
    @LabTestGroupId int
as
begin 
    select TestNames 
    from tbl_LabTests 
    where LabTestGroupId = @LabTestGroupId
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a `string` to your stored procedure when it's expecting an `int`.  Change the code that sets the `@LabTestGroupId` parameter like this.

```
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
    "@LabTestGroupId", 
    int.Parse(cbTestGroup.SelectedValue.Item["LabTestGroupId"].ToString()));
```

Or you need to determine how to convert the `SelectedValue` into the desired `int` value.  I suggest debugging and viewing the `SelectedValue` in the watch window to determine exactly what it is and how to get to the desired value.

Comment: Thanks but its not working.. It says cannot convert from object to string.

Comment: You may need to do `int.Parse(cbTestGroup.SelectedValue.ToString())`.  Try seeing exactly what `SelectedValue` is in the debugger.

Comment: I tried it says input string was not in correct format

Comment: What is the data type of your `tbl_LabTests.LabTestGroupId` column

Comment: Then the `SelectedValue` should be an int, or at least a string that can be turned into an int.  Is that column nullable?  And if so could the `SelectedValue` be for a `null` column?

Comment: Actually the column is not null

Comment: OK I think I know what's going on.  I believe that the `SelectedValue` is a `System.Data.DataRowView`.  I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: yes when i hover over the selected value its shows System.Data.DataRowView.

Comment: Solved it myself i just changed the event to SelectionChangedCommitted.